# Spring Cloud Ribbon Load balance sequence

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-ribbon

[image]

Could anyone with Ribbon experience help me check if my understanding of Ribbon correct.

Comment: Looks accurate at first glance. Do you have any specific doubts or questions?